# Ошибка "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Учусь кодить на Питоне. Не знаю, что я сделал не так...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таким кодом Python  не понимает что это за тип переменной, которую вы ввели.
Попробуйте сменить код на `x=int(input())`.
Даже в самой ошибке сказано про string format

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `%` в Python работает по-разному в зависимости от типа объектов, к которым применяется:

1. Дает остаток от деления, если применяется к числам: `3 % 2 = 1`
2. Для строк применяется как [оператор форматирования](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-operator.html):
   `"Результат равен %s попугаям" % 48` превратится в `"Результат равен 48 попугаям"`

Вы применяете оператор к строкам (функция `input()` возвращает строки), поэтому Python пытается применить второй вариант. Но т.к. в первой строке нет "маркеров" для подстановки (как `%s` внутри строки в примере выше), то получаете ошибку "не все аргументы были преобразованы во время форматирования".

В вашем случае просто нужно преобразовать введенные данные в числа.